# How to shrink at runtime a struct matrix (using realloc() for example)

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, malloc, realloc

How to shrink at runtime a struct `matrix` (using reallocate() for example)

I have a `struct` matrix which I use to set a vector of size 3 with entries (`1`,`2`,`3`). How is it possible to shrink the size of the vector to retain the 2 first elements and remove the third one (the `3`)? I tried to use `realloc()` without success

At the end I would like to have the following output:

```
1 2 3
1 2
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t nrows, ncols;
  size_t *array;
} Matrix ;

int ncol = 3;
int nrow = 1;

void print_matrix(Matrix * matrix);

int main()
{
  Matrix *mat1 = (Matrix *) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
  mat1->nrows = nrow;
  mat1->ncols = ncol;
  mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(int));
  mat1->array[0 * ncol + 0] = 1;
  mat1->array[0 * ncol + 1] = 2;
  mat1->array[0 * ncol + 2] = 3;
  print_matrix(mat1);
  mat1->nrows = mat1->nrows - 1;
  mat1->array = (size_t *) realloc(mat1, nrow * ncol * sizeof(int));
  print_matrix(mat1);
  free(mat1);
}

void print_matrix(Matrix * matrix)
{
  for (size_t row =0; row<matrix->nrows; row++)
  {
    for (size_t col =0; col<matrix->ncols; col++)
    {
      printf("%zu ", matrix->array[row * ncol + col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to the answer here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t nrows, ncols;
  size_t *array;
} Matrix ;

int ncol = 3;
int nrow = 1;

void print_matrix(Matrix * matrix);

int main()
{
  Matrix *mat1 = (Matrix *) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
  mat1->nrows = nrow;
  mat1->ncols = ncol;
  mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
  if (mat1 == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
  {
    mat1->nrows = nrow;
    mat1->ncols = ncol;
    mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
    mat1->array[0 * ncol + 0] = 1;
    mat1->array[0 * ncol + 1] = 2;
    mat1->array[0 * ncol + 2] = 3;
    print_matrix(mat1);
    mat1->ncols = mat1->ncols - 1;
    mat1->array = (size_t *) realloc(mat1->array, mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
    if (mat1 == NULL)
    {
      printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    print_matrix(mat1);
    free(mat1);
  }
}

void print_matrix(Matrix * matrix)
{
  for (size_t row =0; row<matrix->nrows; row++)
  {
    for (size_t col =0; col<matrix->ncols; col++)
    {
      printf("%zu ", matrix->array[row * ncol + col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Aside: Do not cast the return of `malloc()` and family, but do check its return value. It returns `NULL` to indicate failure.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` should be `sizeof(size_t)`. And `[0 * ncol + 0]` is equivalent to `[0]`.

Comment: I think you need to work with an example which has more than one row, and use a double pointer. With a one-dimensional array you'll have to reorganise its content when you change its size.

Comment: If ```mat1->array = (size_t *) realloc(mat1, nrow * ncol * sizeof(int));``` fails, you would lose access to the original memory allocated through `malloc()`. Use a temporary pointer to hold `realloc()`'s value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should reduce the number of columsn, not rows.
- Not `mat1` but `mat1->array` should be reallocated.
- Not `nrow` and `ncol` (not updated) but `mat1->nrows` and `mat1->ncols` (updated) should be used for the new size.
- The elements are `size_t`, so allocating for `int` mayn't be enough. Using the variable for calculating size is safe.

In the other words, this part

```c
  mat1->nrows = mat1->nrows - 1;
  mat1->array = (size_t *) realloc(mat1, nrow * ncol * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```c
  mat1->ncols = mat1->ncols - 1;
  mat1->array = (size_t *) realloc(mat1->array, mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
```

and the part (the 4th line of `main()` body)

```c
  mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
  mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
```

Note that this simple reallocation works only because the matrix has only one row. For matrice having multiple rows, you should move (using `memmove` or manually) second and later rows to match the new number of columns.

Comment: Also, in `print_matrix`, global `ncol` is used in one place.

Comment: *you should move (using `memmove` or manually) second and later rows to match the new number of columns.*  And that must be done **before** calling `realloc()` if you're shrinking the array, and **after** calling `realloc()` if you're growing the array.